# exponential RV til bus arrives

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

Suppose that you are waiting at a bus stop. The waiting time until a bus arrives is $T$ where $T$ is an exponentially distributed random variable with parameter $λ$ i.e. $P(T≤t)=1−e^{−λt}, ∀t≥0$. 
(a) Given that you have already waited $r$ seconds, what is the probability that the bus will not arrive within $d$ more seconds? 
(b) What is the average waiting time for the bus i.e. the expected value of $T$? Hint: Recall that one way to solve $\int u \, dv$ is by integration by parts.

My attempt:

(a) If we've waited $r$ seconds and seeing if the bus will not arrive in $d$ more seconds, then we're calculating $1-P(T≤r+d)$ which is $1-(1−e^{−λ(r+d)}) = e^{−λ(r+d)}$

(b) The PDF of an exponential RV is $f(x)=λe^{-λx}$. The average waiting time would be $\int_0^\infty xλe^{-λx} \, dx$ which, after integration, equals $\frac{1}{λ}$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to (b) is correct, although if this is an exercise to be turned in, a correct answer for that purpose would probably show the details of how the integration is done.

But (a) asks for a **conditional** probability. Recall that
$$
\Pr(A\mid B) = \frac{\Pr(A\ \&\ B)}{\Pr(B)}.
$$

Comment: I see. So in this case A is the bus won't arrive in d more seconds and B is you've waited r seconds and the bus hasn't arrived yet. So P(A & B) is ^−λ(+). And P(B) is ^−λ(), right?

Comment: Therefore final answer is −λ

Comment: @IrCa : Yes. $\qquad$